# setCustomValidity Bootstrap keep error popup

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've implement localization in my application, all this stuff is saved inside a php file. So I can easy do this:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" required="" placeholder="username" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('<?php echo $this->lang->line('field_required'); ?>')"></input>
```

Now if I doesn't enter any text I can see the custom message, but if I fill the input I see again the popup as the form can't get the text inside.

It's a  bug of Bootstrap?

**EXAMPLE**

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23662/

Comment: i'm able to see the popup even after entering text.

Comment: @Iceman Infact, this is the problem

Comment: wud you be interested in another method. `oninvalid` is not cross-browser gr8. for ex. safari doesnt support it.

Comment: @Iceman which method? Tell me please, I also found a workarounf, check my answer, but hope to see best answer.

Comment: that is what i saying. using javascript though

Comment: @Iceman could you show an example please?

Comment: Sure. i'll add an answer

Comment: so do you want to check for email or just input with length > 0?

Comment: @iceman when the input contains required I need to display a custom message. This message is contained inside a php file that I can grab from js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `onvalid` won't work in some browsers like Safari or IE below 10. Use a custom event notifier for attaching the function.

Note: As you mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38940498/setcustomvalidity-bootstrap-keep-error-popup/38941060#comment65237172_38940498) you can print the message from the `data-invalid-message` attribute from php and catch it using jQuery by `.data('invalidMessage')`.

**SEE WORKING EXAMPLE:**

```js
var myobj = jQuery('input.form-control');
myobj.on('keyup keypress blur change input', function() {
  var messg = ($(this).data('invalidMessage'));
  if (this.validity.typeMismatch) {
    this.setCustomValidity(messg);
  } else {
    this.setCustomValidity('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input class="form-control" type="email" required placeholder="username" data-invalid-message="custom message from php here">
  <button type="submit">
    go
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: uhm why I can't see the text `please enter valid email?`

Comment: This will catch event like `ctrl+v` or `cmd+v` or `right-click>paste` which won't work with keypress.

Comment: there is a command in js that allow me to display the popup calling as: inputId.showCustomValidity() ?

Answer (score 1):

a workaround that I've found is:

```
onkeyup="this.setCustomValidity('');
```

the bug will be gone now.

Answer (score 1):

**TL&DR**
Check `element.validity.typeMismatch` and then `element.setCustomValidity('custom error msg')` or `element.setCustomValidity('')` if there's no mismatch. You should listen on both `keyup` and `blur` events.

Explanation in Mozilla Developer documentation about `setCustomValidity`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation#Customized_error_messages.

But just keyup won't work properly if focus is not inside the input box we're modyfing.

> Our previous example won't transfer the current state of the input box
>   if the user mouses away and clicks elsewhere on the page. We update
>   the component's values property only when the user presses Enter while
>   the focus is inside the input box.
>
> Let's fix that by listening to the input box's blur event as well.

Above is from Angular 2 docs: User Input, paragraph "On blur" https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html.

**Simplified example**

Below is example from Mozilla documentation with added `blur` keyEvent listener. Yup, refactoring needed, but mine version in Angular 2 looks vastly different and so probably will yours.

```
<form>
  <label for="mail">I would like you to provide me an e-mail</label>
  <input type="email" id="mail" name="mail">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

And then

```
var email = document.getElementById("mail");

email.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
  if (email.validity.typeMismatch) {
    email.setCustomValidity("I expect an e-mail, darling!");
  } else {
    email.setCustomValidity("");
  }
});

email.addEventListener("blur", function (event) {
  if (email.validity.typeMismatch) {
    email.setCustomValidity("I expect an e-mail, darling!");
  } else {
    email.setCustomValidity("");
  }
});
```